# org.jinterop.dcom.common.JIException: Message not found for errorCode: 0xC0000070

Tags: java, j-integra

```
public class JIntegra  {

    private static final String WMI_DEFAULT_NAMESPACE = "ROOT\\CIMV2";

    private static JISession configAndConnectDCom( String domain, String user, String pass ) throws Exception
    {
        JISystem.getLogger().setLevel( Level.OFF );
        try
        {
            JISystem.setInBuiltLogHandler( false );
        }
        catch ( IOException ignored )
        {
        }

        JISystem.setAutoRegisteration( true );
        JISession dcomSession = JISession.createSession( domain, user, pass );
        dcomSession.useSessionSecurity( true );
        return dcomSession;
    }


    private static IJIDispatch getWmiLocator( String host, JISession dcomSession ) throws Exception
    {

            JIComServer wbemLocatorComObj = new JIComServer(JIProgId.valueOf("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator"), host, dcomSession);
            return (IJIDispatch) JIObjectFactory.narrowObject( wbemLocatorComObj.createInstance().queryInterface( IJIDispatch.IID ) );
    }


    private static IJIDispatch toIDispatch( JIVariant comObjectAsVariant ) throws JIException
    {
        return (IJIDispatch) JIObjectFactory.narrowObject( comObjectAsVariant.getObjectAsComObject() );
    }


    public static void main( String[] args )
    {

        String domain = "syntbots.com";

 //     String host = "syncgdc3244";
        String host = "192.168.175.65";
        String user = "VK5017063";
        String pass = "apr@2016";

        JISession dcomSession = null;


        try
        {
            dcomSession = configAndConnectDCom( domain, user, pass );
            IJIDispatch wbemLocator = getWmiLocator( host, dcomSession );

            JIVariant results[] =
                    wbemLocator.callMethodA( "ConnectServer", new Object[] { new JIString( host ), new JIString( WMI_DEFAULT_NAMESPACE ),
                            JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM(), JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM(), JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM(), JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM(), new Integer( 0 ),
                            JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM() } );


            IJIDispatch wbemServices = toIDispatch( results[ 0 ] );

            final String QUERY_FOR_ALL_LOG_EVENTS = "SELECT * FROM Win32_OperatingSystem";
            final int RETURN_IMMEDIATE = 16;
            final int FORWARD_ONLY = 32;

            JIVariant[] eventSourceSet =
                    wbemServices.callMethodA( "ExecNotificationQuery", new Object[] { new JIString( QUERY_FOR_ALL_LOG_EVENTS ), new JIString( "WQL" ),
                            new JIVariant( new Integer( RETURN_IMMEDIATE + FORWARD_ONLY ) ) } );
            IJIDispatch wbemEventSource = (IJIDispatch) JIObjectFactory.narrowObject( ( eventSourceSet[ 0 ] ).getObjectAsComObject() );


            while ( true )
            {

                JIVariant eventAsVariant = (JIVariant) ( wbemEventSource.callMethodA( "NextEvent", new Object[] { JIVariant.OPTIONAL_PARAM() } ) )[ 0 ];
                IJIDispatch wbemEvent = toIDispatch( eventAsVariant );



                JIVariant objTextAsVariant = (JIVariant) ( wbemEvent.callMethodA( "GetObjectText_", new Object[] { new Integer( 1 ) } ) )[ 0 ];
                String asText = objTextAsVariant.getObjectAsString().getString();
                System.out.println( asText );
            }
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally
        {
            if ( null != dcomSession )
            {
                try
                {
                     JISession.destroySession( dcomSession );
                }
                catch ( Exception ex )
                {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please find the below error

```
org.jinterop.dcom.common.JIException: Message not found for errorCode: 0xC0000070
    at org.jinterop.winreg.smb.JIWinRegStub.winreg_OpenHKLM(JIWinRegStub.java:115)
    at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIProgId.getIdFromWinReg(JIProgId.java:130)
    at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIProgId.getCorrespondingCLSID(JIProgId.java:162)
    at org.jinterop.dcom.core.JIComServer.<init>(JIComServer.java:429)
    at JIntegra.getWmiLocator(JIntegra.java:43)
    at JIntegra.main(JIntegra.java:94)
Caused by: jcifs.smb.SmbAuthException: Logon failure: user not allowed to log on to this computer.
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.checkStatus(SmbTransport.java:510)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTransport.send(SmbTransport.java:622)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.sessionSetup(SmbSession.java:280)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbSession.send(SmbSession.java:233)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbTree.treeConnect(SmbTree.java:154)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.doConnect(SmbFile.java:847)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect(SmbFile.java:890)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.connect0(SmbFile.java:816)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFileInputStream.<init>(SmbFileInputStream.java:73)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFileInputStream.<init>(SmbFileInputStream.java:62)
    at jcifs.smb.SmbFile.getInputStream(SmbFile.java:2765)
    at rpc.ncacn_np.RpcTransport.attach(RpcTransport.java:91)
    at rpc.Stub.attach(Stub.java:106)
    at rpc.Stub.call(Stub.java:110)
    at org.jinterop.winreg.smb.JIWinRegStub.winreg_OpenHKLM(JIWinRegStub.java:113)
```

Comment: What is your question? The error message "Logon failure: user not allowed to log on to this computer" seems pretty clear.

Comment: Should I do any configuration so that it allows users to log into the computer...?

Answer (score 0):

I found the way by Jacob

```
ActiveXComponent wmi = new ActiveXComponent("WbemScripting.SWbemLocator");        


Variant variantParameters[] =  new Variant[4];
variantParameters[0] = new Variant("hostname");
variantParameters[1] = new Variant("root\\cimv2");
variantParameters[2] = new Variant("domain\\username");
variantParameters[3] = new Variant("password");

  ActiveXComponent axWMI;
try
{   
    com.jacob.com.Variant conRet =  wmi.invoke("ConnectServer", variantParameters);     
    axWMI = new ActiveXComponent(conRet.toDispatch());

}catch(ComFailException e)
{

    e.printStackTrace();
    axWMI = null;
}
if (axWMI == null)
{
    System.out.println("Connection not established");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("Connection  established");
    String query =  "Select Name from Win32_ComputerSystem";
    Variant vCollection = axWMI.invoke("ExecQuery", new Variant(query));

    EnumVariant enumVariant = new EnumVariant(vCollection.toDispatch());

    String resultString = "";
    Dispatch item = null;
    item = enumVariant.nextElement().toDispatch();
    String name = Dispatch.call(item, "Name").toString();
    resultString += ( " name " + name);
    System.out.println(resultString);
}
```